# Get matching Lon / Lat records within a bounding box from Google Maps

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I'm working with some Google maps bounding box lon/lat points and need to find all the records in a MySql database with lon/lat's that reside within that box.

Any help would be amazing!

Here's the data I'm playing with:

```
((-30.14348404555906,132.20886239843753),(-27.740202928232875,135.99914560156253))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without any other geo index, you need to go through all the records in your database to see if it falls in that box

```
-30.14348404555906 < lat < -27.740202928232875
```

and

```
132.20886239843753 < lng < 135.99914560156253
```

If you need to do lots of these kind of operations and your database is big, I recommend you use some geospatial structures like [rtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), or consider using lucene/solr